# How to edit notebook (.ipynb) settings in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, settings

In the may update documentation for Notebooks in VS Code I noticed that we now have a few more settings to play with and change up -- I was just wondering how exactly to implement those settings (specifically displaying text alongside the icons in the toolbar)

Do we just change/add the "settings.json" file  or how would we implement these settings?

Comment: Go to the Extensions Tab. Over there, find the Jupyter Extension and click the small settings icon next to the Disable button. I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text with their icons, there is a new setting in vscode v1.59:

`Notebook: Global Toolbar Show Label`:  `always`

```
you can now toggle the text labels on the notebook toolbar using the setting  
 `notebook.globalToolbarShowLabel`.
```

or (in vscode 1.63):

> When set to `dynamic`, the notebook toolbar will hide labels of actions
> on the notebook toolbar, from the right most group to the left, group
> by group, when the viewport shrinks. At last, if the viewport is still
> too narrow, it will then move the actions (starting from the right
> most ones) to the overflow menu.